# getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail no longer returning data

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I use a Python script to retrieve Teams user activity details. Stats are requested for two days prior. On 14 Dec, the script successfully retrieved data from 12 December. On 15 December, the report for activity on 13 Dec was all zeros. This condition has continued through today. I've added a line to print the result from the Graph call, and found there is no user detail:

```
jsonResponse = json.loads(strJSONResponse)
strAccessToken = jsonResponse['access_token']
getHeader = {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + strAccessToken
}

r2 = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(date={0})".format(yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), headers=getHeader)
strUsageReport = r2.text
print(strUsageReport)
```

While I am getting no errors, the expected column headers *are* returned.

```
[lisa@host ~]# python genReport.py
Getting stats from 2018-12-15
Report Refresh Date,User Principal Name,Last Activity Date,Is Deleted,Deleted Date,Assigned Products,Team Chat Message Count,Private Chat Message Count,Call Count,Meeting Count,Has Other Action,Report Period

Sending POST request to strURL=https://outlook.office.com/webhook/.../IncomingWebhook/...
```

If I change the script to get data from 12 Dec, the data is gathered and processed as expected (i.e. my code and permissions are fine), but any date from the 13th on yields no information.

Is anyone else having problems with the getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail call for recent data?

Comment: Are you able to recieve data for the 14th forward (i.e. is this _only_ the 13th or _since_ the 13th)?

Comment: There is no data in the report from the 13th onward. I've changed my date.today() - timedelta(#) to test from today back until I started seeing data again. First date I see anything more than column headers is 12 Dec.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you switch from `date={date}` to `period='D30'`?

Comment: Nope, I get data for period='D7' or period='D30' ... I'm not sure if my period range data includes stats from the past few days, but there are users listed & a lot of us have activity reported.

Comment: Just realized, in both D7 and D30 period-based reports, the most recent 'Last Activity Date' and "Report Refresh Date" value is 12 December as well.

Comment: I was afraid that might be what you were seeing. I'd check the [user activity report in the O365 portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-activity-reports) and see if that has the same issue (I suspect it might) If that _is_ the case, I'd recommend opening a support request (i.e. it may mean it is related to your tenant rather than an issue in the API itself).

Comment: Thank you; checking the O365 portal report is a good way to validate that *something* has gone awry in the data feed and not Graph. Our line for Teams ends on 12 Dec in the portal usage report too. We'll get a case opened up & see if someone can get our tenant reporting again.